# Making combinations of attributes unique in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is an option in postgresql where we can have a constraint such that we can have multiple attributes of a table together as unique

```
UNIQUE (A, B, C)
```

Is it possible to take attributes from multiple tables and make their entire combination as unique in some way

Edit:

Table 1: List of Book
Attributes: ID, Title, Year, Publisher

Table 2: List of Author
Attributes: Name, ID

Table 3: Written By: Relation between Book and Author
Attributes: Book_ID, Author_ID

Now I have situation where I don't want (Title, Year, Publisher, Authors) get repeated in my entire database

Comment: Please could you code an example of what you are thinking of and share a fiddle?

Comment: hi sidewala, have you checked [Erwin answer on partial unique index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9760)? hope it works for your case.

Comment: This talks about the case for within the same table, but in my case I want to use multiple tables. Also I want the case where if a book has multiple authors then in that case also the book should not be repeated

Comment: Nothing is repeated. The table books contains books, the table authors contains authors. Both are (assumed to be) unique.

Comment: No I specifically want those tuples to be unique when they are together for a particular book

Comment: Maybe you want an aggregating query, aggregating the list of authors per book, or the list op books per author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 solutions to this problem:

1. You add a column "authorID" to the table "book", as a foreign key. You can then add the `UNIQUE` constraint to the table "book".
   We can have a foreign key on the 2 columns (bookID, author ID) which references the table bookAuthor.
2. You create a Trigger on insert on the table "book" which checks whether the combination exist and does not insert if it does exist. You will find a working example of this option below.
   Whilst working on this option I realised that the JOIN to WrittenBy must be done on Title and not ID. Otherwise we can record the same book as many times as we like just by using a new ID. The problem with using the title is that the slightest change in spelling or punctuation means that it is treated as a new title.
   In the example the 3rd insert has failed because it already exists. In the 4th have left 2 spaces in "Tom  Sawyer" and it is accepted as a different title.
   Also as we use a join to find out the author the real effect of our rule is exactly the same as if we had a UNIQUE constraint on the table books on columns Title, Year and Publisher. This means that all that I have coded is a waste of time.
   We thus decide, after coding it, that this option is not effective.
3. We could create a fourth table with the 4 columns and a UNIQUE constraint on all 4. This seems a heavy solution compared to option 1.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Book (
>   ID int primary key, 
>   Title varchar(25), 
>   Year int, 
>   Publisher varchar(10) );
>
> CREATE TABLE Author (
>   ID int primary key,
>   Name varchar(10)
>   );
>
> CREATE TABLE WrittenBy(
>   Book_ID int primary key, 
>   Titlew varchar(25),
>   Author_ID int 
>   );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION book_insert_trigger_function() 
>    RETURNS TRIGGER 
>    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
> AS $$
> DECLARE 
> authID INTEGER;
> coun INTEGER;
> BEGIN
>     IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
>         RETURN NEW;
>     END IF;
>     SELECT MAX(Author_ID) into authID 
>          FROM WrittenBy w
>          WHERE w.Titlew = NEW.Title;
>     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO coun FROM 
>                 Book b LEFT JOIN WrittenBy w ON
>                 b.Title = w.Titlew
>                 WHERE NEW.year = b.year
>                   AND NEW.title=b.title
>                   AND NEW.publisher=b.publisher
>                   AND authID = COALESCE(w.Author_ID,authID);
>         IF coun > 0 THEN
>      RETURN null; -- this means that we do not insert
>   ELSE
>      RETURN NEW;
>   END IF;
> END;
> $$
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER book_insert_trigger
>    BEFORE INSERT
>    ON Book
>    FOR EACH ROW
>        EXECUTE PROCEDURE book_insert_trigger_function();
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO WrittenBy VALUES
> (1,'Tom Sawyer',1),
> (2,'Huckleberry Finn',1);
> INSERT INTO Book VALUES (1,'Tom Sawyer',1950,'Classics');
> INSERT INTO Book VALUES (2,'Huckleberry Finn',1950,'Classics');
> INSERT INTO Book VALUES (3,'Tom Sawyer',1950,'Classics');
> INSERT INTO Book VALUES (3,'Tom  Sawyer',1950,'Classics');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM Book b 
> LEFT JOIN WrittenBy w on w.Titlew = b.Title
> LEFT JOIN Author a on w.author_ID = a.ID;
> ```

```
> 
> id | title            | year | publisher | book_id | titlew           | author_id |   id | name
> -: | :--------------- | ---: | :-------- | ------: | :--------------- | --------: | ---: | :---
>  1 | Tom Sawyer       | 1950 | Classics  |       1 | Tom Sawyer       |         1 | null | null
>  2 | Huckleberry Finn | 1950 | Classics  |       2 | Huckleberry Finn |         1 | null | null
>  3 | Tom  Sawyer      | 1950 | Classics  |    null | null             |      null | null | null
>
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9f4b48ea4963bee1facd6ddd4b064e8)*

Comment: What if a book has multiple authors? Will this work in that case?